# Programm sucking more and more RAM after closing images with PIL.Image

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

So, I write a code who put bunch of images into PFD.

```py
            for fname in filer:  # for filename in filerepertory
                path1 = path + "\\" + fname
                img = Image.open(path1)
                imglist.append(img)

            start = imglist[0]  # init the first image of the PDF
            del imglist[0]
            name = chapname + ".pdf"
            start.save(self.name+"\\"+name, "PDF", save_all=True, resolution=100, append_images=imglist)
            start.close()
```

All things work perfectly but right after `start.save(...)`, my programm suck ≈200MB of RAM more, and after every loop it took 200Mb more until the memory error.
I don't know why it keep it into the RAM after `start.close()`.

**PS :** I try to modify the way I encode previously the images.
I convert images to .jpg with this code `Image.open(path1).convert('RGB').save(path1[:-3]+"done.jpg")`, and after, for the PDF convertion, it add ≈200MB.
I tried that `Image.open(path1).convert('L').save(path1[:-3]+"done.jpg")` (so encode in white and black not with colors), and it took just ≈20MB of RAM instead of ≈200MB...

I'm stuck with this problem for 3 days now and I really don't know how to solve this problem so, if anyone have any clues...

Comment: have you tired to delete the start object?

Comment: Yup, I tried to delet literally all variables after I used it x)

Comment: Please use the internationally agreed symbol `MB` for megabytes https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte